# Phonon can't get meta data of audio files in Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, phonon

I have problems getting the meta data of audio files (ogg and mp3) using Python bindings to Phonon which is part of Qt 4.8.

In particular I tried PySide 1.2.1 on Python 3.3 on Windows 7 and Linux Ubuntu 13.10 and the official [musicplayer example](https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/source/060dca8e4b82f301dfb33a7182767eaf8ad3d024:examples/phonon/musicplayer.py) when stopped after line 156:

```
metaData = self.metaInformationResolver.metaData()
```

and inspecting metaData gives nothing (`{}`) although the selected file had meta data.

I see the same behavior in my example script:

```
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide.phonon import Phonon

def state_changed(newState, oldState):
    print('state change {} : {}'.format(oldState, newState))
    if newState == Phonon.ErrorState:
        print('error {} : {}'.format(media_object.errorType(), media_object.errorString()))

def meta_changed():
    meta_data = media_object.metaData()
    print('meta change = {}'.format(meta_data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication([])
    app.setApplicationName('test')

    audio_output = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.MusicCategory)
    media_object = Phonon.MediaObject()
    Phonon.createPath(media_object, audio_output)

    media_object.metaDataChanged.connect(meta_changed)
    media_object.stateChanged.connect(state_changed)
    media_object.setCurrentSource('test.ogg')
    media_object.play()

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, meta_changed) # just to check that there is really no meta data

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, app.quit)
    app.exec_()
```

which outputs to:

```
meta change = {}
state change PySide.phonon.Phonon.State.LoadingState : PySide.phonon.Phonon.State.PlayingState
meta change = {}
```

**So is it a deficient implementation of Phonon or am I doing something wrong?**

There is one more question here from 2012 about [not getting the meta data on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959576/phonon-cant-get-metadata-on-mac) and it was not resolved.

Please try the official Qt musicplayer example or my example script above in PySide, PyQt or even C++ and tell me if or how you can get the meta data of the audio files. Tell me what configuration you use and if it runs or not.

Comment: Works fine for me using PySide-1.2.1 or PyQt4-4.10.4 with Qt-4.8.5 on Arch Linux (gstreamer backend).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for the test. Btw. how do you determine the backend in use?

Comment: I don't know of any programmatic way to do it. On my Arch Linux system, I only have the gstreamer backend installed. The DE should probably provide some way of selecting the preferred one to use. I know that for KDE, there is a Phonon Configuration Module that does this (it's accessible via the System Settings, IIRC).